# How the word 'die' have both meanings that something stop living and that the dice

Tags: single-word-requests, etymology

The oxford dictionary describes that the word 'die' means that something stops living.
But it also means the dice(or die, for gambling).

Is there any historical story behind it?
Sorry for poor grammar, English is my second language.
I really want to know it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two terms have the same spelling but different origins; it appears that there is no relationship
between them:

***[Die](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=die)*** - noun:

> - early 14c. (as a plural, late 14c. as a singular), from Old French de "die, dice," which is of uncertain origin.

***Die*** - verb:

> - mid-12c., possibly from Old Danish døja or Old Norse deyja "to die, pass away," both from Proto-Germanic *dawjan (source also of Old Frisian deja "to kill," Old Saxon doian, Old High German touwen, Gothic diwans "mortal"), from PIE root *dheu.

(etymonline)